# How to take table data from a website using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website that has a table in it using bs4, but the element of the content I'm getting is not as complete compared to the one I get from inspect. I cannot find the tag `<tr>` and `<td>` in it.  How can I get the full content of that site especially the tags for the table?

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = requests.get("https://pemilu2019.kpu.go.id/#/ppwp/hitung-suara/", verify = False)
src = link.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

I expect the content to have the tag `<tr>` and `<td>` in it because they do exist when I inspect it,but I found none from the output.

[Here's the image of the page where there is the tag `<tr>` and `<td>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paCsh.png)

Comment: You should start by fixing the URL.

Comment: That's the correct url, I have just edited it. Could you help me with that?

Comment: URL is not accessible for me.

Comment: Website probably loads that data into the table after page load.

Comment: I can't load that page in my browser. I think WillardSolutions is onto something. Perhaps the data for the table is created by JavaScript, maybe even after an AJAX request, so that it isn't directly in the initial response from the server.

Comment: I have included the image of the website above, could you have a look please? Maybe you can find the problem from just the image?

Comment: @NuhYamin When you view that page in the browser, when does the table appear? Does it appear immediately or do you have to select things in the dropdowns first?

Comment: No, when I view the page I don't have to select anything from the dropdowns. But it seems like the dropdowns appear first then followed by the table after a few seconds. Is that the problem?

Comment: write soup to a txt file and then copy paste that into pastebin.com and share the link to that maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should dump the contents of the text you're trying to parse to a file and look at it.  This will tell you for sure what is and isn't there.  Like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = requests.get("https://pemilu2019.kpu.go.id/#/ppwp/hitung-suara/", verify = False)
src = link.content
with open("/tmp/content.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(src)
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Run this code, and then look at the file "/tmp/content.html" (use a different path, obviously, if you're on Windows), and look at what is actually in the file.  You could probably do this with your browser, but this this is the way to be the most sure you know what you are getting. You could, of course, also just add `print(src)`, but if it were me, I'd dump it to a file

If the HTML you're looking for is not in the initial HTML that you're getting back, then that HTML is coming from somewhere else.  The table could be being built dynamically by JavaScript, or coming from another URL reference, possibly one that calls an HTTP API to grab the table's HTML via parameters passed to the API endpoint.

You will have to reverse engineer the site's design to find where that HTML comes from.  If it comes from JavaScript, you may be stuck short of scripting the execution of a browser so you can gain access programmatically to the DOM in the browser's memory.

I would recommend running a debugging proxy that will show you each HTTP request being made by your browser.  You'll be able to see the contents of each request and response.  If you can do this, you can find the URL that actually returns the content you're looking for, if such a URL exists.  You'll have to deal with SSL certificates and such because this is a https endpoint.  Debugging proxies usually make that pretty easy.  We use [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). The standard browser toolboxes might do this too...allow you to see each request and response that is generated by a particular page load.

If you can discover the URL that actually returns the table HTML, then you can use that URL to grab it and parse it with BS.

Comment: I did that but still couldn't see any tags for the table, there are only <head>, <title>,  <body>, <link>, and <script>. It's only a few lines of tags. I don't know why.